# nsswitch.conf versus host.conf

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking

Suppose that `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file contains

```
hosts: files dns
```

and `/etc/host.conf` file has

```
order bind,hosts
```

then in which order the system would use `/etc/hosts` and DNS look-up to resolve a host name? In other words, which of the two configuration files takes precedence?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`/etc/nsswitch.conf` is the default file for domain name resolution these days. I have the following line at the top of my `/etc/host.conf` file:-

```
# The "order" line is only used by old versions of the C library.
```

`nsswitch.conf` is used by pretty much everything on my Debian box for name resolution. So, given the above lines in your files, the default name resolution order would be to check `/etc/hosts` first, and then use the nameservers configured in `/etc/resolv.conf` to do a DNS lookup.

Lately (since about Ubuntu 11.10), the `/etc/resolv.conf` is by default configured to use the localhost interface (127.0.0.1), where a daemon program `dnsmasq` listens on port 53 for DNS requests. This in turn usually does DNS resolution as configured by your LAN's DHCP server, but this can be manually overridden in the OS's network configuration GUI.

Note: You didn't mention what OS you are using, and the above is coming from personal experience with Debian Ubuntu. The defaults might be different on different flavours of Linux