# How do `/etc/hosts` and DNS work together to resolve hostnames to IP addresses?

Tags: linux, dns, hosts, host-name-resolution

In Linux, how do `/etc/hosts` and DNS work together to resolve hostnames to IP addresses?

1. if a hostname can be resolved in `/etc/hosts`, does DNS apply after `/etc/hosts`
   to resolve the hostname or treat the resolved IP address by
   `/etc/hosts` as a "hostname" to resolve recursively?
2. In my browser (firefox and google chrome), when I add to
   `/etc/hosts`:

   ```
   127.0.0.1 google.com www.google.com
   ```

   typing www.google.com into the address bar of the browsers and
   hitting entering won't connect to the website.  After I remove that
   line from `/etc/hosts`, I can connect to the website. Does it mean
   that `/etc/hosts` overrides DNS for resolving hostnames?

   After I re-add the line to `/etc/hosts`, I can still connect to the
   website, even after refreshing the webpage.  Why doesn't
   `/etc/hosts` apply again, so that I can't connect to the website?

Thanks.

Comment: Beware that many Web browsers implement their own DNS servers and DNS cache and do not consult any name-lookup mechanisms that have been configured on the system. In other words, some Web browsers completely ignore `/etc/hosts` and the locally-defined name servers. It's quite confusing to witness the first time around. (Looking at you, Chromium-based browsers!)

Comment: @Christopher I was coming here to say the same thing. Related https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363498/why-does-chromium-not-cache-dns-for-more-than-a-minute/363501#363501

Comment: @Christopher After I re-add the line to /etc/hosts, I can still connect to the website, even after refreshing the webpage. Why doesn't /etc/hosts apply again, so that I can't connect to the website? Is it because of DNS cache of Firefox?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro This Chromium build seems to respect `/etc/hosts` and the system-defined DNS servers: (https://github.com/Eloston/ungoogled-chromium). Installation on macOS with Homebrew: `brew cask install eloston-chromium`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is dictated by the NSS (Name Service Switch) configuration i.e. `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file's `hosts` directive. For example, on my system:

```
hosts:    files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
```

Here, `files` refers to the `/etc/hosts` file, and `dns` refers to the DNS system. And as you can imagine *whichever comes first wins*.

Also, see `man 5 nsswitch.conf` to get more idea on this.

---

As an aside, to follow the NSS host resolution orderings, use `getent` with `hosts` as database e.g.:

```
getent hosts example.com
```

Comment: Thanks. In my part 2, is it because my web browser's DNS server does not work, but web browser's DNS cache works?

Comment: How does `systemd.resolver` affects resolutions? Where do NIS and LDAP fit into the resolution system? What order follows a MacOS system or a Windows system?.

Comment: @Tim Yes, your browser is fetching the data from cache.

Answer (score 10):

To answer just your last question: `/etc/hosts` doesn't apply again immediately because `firefox` is caching the last hostname it got for `google.com`; if you want it to always fetch it again, you'll have to set [`network.dnsCacheExpiration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Preferences/Mozilla_networking_preferences#DNS) to `0` in `about:config`. More info (though a bit outdated) [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.dnsCacheExpiration). Sorry if this is offtopic.

---

As a sidenote, many programs don't use the standard resolver (`getaddrinfo(3)`, `getnameinfo(3)` [1]) because *it sucks*.

First, the interface is not asynchronous; any moderately complex program will have to spawn a separate thread doing just the `getaddrinfo()` and then invent its own protocol to communicate with it (and let's not even enter into `getaddrinfo_a()`, which is sending a *signal* upon completion, so it's even worse).

Second, the resolver implementation in `glibc` (the standard C library in linux) is horrible, expecting you to let it pull random dynamic objects into the address space via `dlopen()` behind your back, and making it impossible to contain it in any way or use it in statically linked executables.

Since many programs don't use the standard resolver directly, they also don't bother to replicate its behavior exactly, and ignore some or all of `/etc/resolv.conf`, `/etc/hosts`, `/etc/nsswitch.conf` or `/etc/gai.conf`.

[1] and don't even mention the non-reentrant, ipv4-only `gethostbyname()`, which was deprecated since ages.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean "non-reentrant"?

Comment: It means that if you're doing a `google = GHBN("google.com"); facebook = GHBN("facebook.com")` you may end up with both `google` and `facebook` containing the address of `facebook.com`. When the two calls are done in different threads, it's even funnier: you may end with an address which is half google and half facebook or complete garbage.

Comment: What has replaced `gethostbyname()` now?

Comment: `getaddrinfo` is the standard function for that, but is itself brokrn, as I already explained, so it's not used as is by browsers or other real-life apps.

Comment: Indeed firefox and Chrome use their own resolves, for instance. Thanks for the insightful notes.

Answer (score 8):

The file `/etc/hosts` and the DNS don't work together. They provide independent resolutions of names (network names).

The glue that links them is [inside `/etc/nsswitch.conf` for linux systems](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52954/nsswitch-conf-versus-host-conf/52964#52964). In `/etc/netsvc.conf` for AIX servers, in the system for [Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/172218/microsoft-tcp-ip-host-name-resolution-order) and could be listed with `lookupd -configuration` (search for LookupOrder, similar to: `Cache FF DNS NI DS`) in MacOS systems.

The actual order becomes complex and usually convoluted as each name resolution service could (and many times do) look inside other levels of resolution. Like `dnsmasq` (a light DNS server generally at `127.0.0.1:53`, or `::1:53` (or both)) usually reads and includes the `/etc/hosts` file contents. Or like `systemd.resolver` (a basic resolver that should only resolve un-dotted names like `mycomputer`) calls directly DNS resolutions for dotted names (`mycomputer.here.dev.`) under some conditions.

In general, services are called in order and the first one that doesn't fail wins and is accepted as the correct address. The general basic order is: `/etc/hosts` (file), mDNS (un-dotted names), DNS, NIS, NIS+, LDAP. In some linux systems there is a last resort resolution for [the computer `hostname` in the service `myhostname`](https://techwiser.com/clear-dns-cache-on-browser/)

For example, in this system (from `cat /etc/nsswitch`):

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname
```

Note that the very old (glibc 2.4 and earlier) `order` entry [set in `/etc/host.conf`](http://www.linfo.org/etc_host_conf.html) as:

```
order hosts,bind,nis
```

Only apply to the files (file `/etc/hosts`) name service.

The effects on this (linux) client computer related to NIS and LDAP are (usually) controlled by the DNS server used (bind, unbound, etc.).

so:

> 1. If a hostname can be resolved in /etc/hosts, does DNS apply after /etc/hosts to resolve the hostname or treat the resolved IP address by /etc/hosts as a "hostname" to resolve recursively?

None.

If a hostname can be resolved in `/etc/hosts`, the `DNS` doesn't apply (if files is before DNS).

**nor** is the resolved IP address treated as a "hostname".

It simply is: the resolved address.

#### browser

A browser could use any method to resolve a name (after it has checked its cache of resolved names). Only if it uses a system provided method the order given above apply. The browser, as any program, could choose to contact any DNS server directly.

If the system order has `/etc/hosts` before `DNS`, it means that an entry in that file will take precedence to `DNS` resolution service.

So:

> 2. ... Does it mean that /etc/hosts overrides DNS for resolving hostnames?

Yes (if the browser use the system provided resolution).

> Why doesn't `/etc/hosts` apply again, so that I can't connect to the website?

Only until the browser internal cache is cleared (or it times out) for that specific name is that name searched outside of the browser again.

If the browser has a name resolved in its cache, the browser uses it again.

[Use this to clear the cache](https://techwiser.com/clear-dns-cache-on-browser/).

Or simply close (wait a while) and re-start the browser.